# Bone does not respect "child of" constraint on a riggified armature

Tags: rigging

I have a character with a riggified armature.

[image]

I added a sword to its hand. The sword has a bone attached to it.

[image]

I added a "child of "constraint on that sword bone. The target is the character's metarig and the bone targetted is the right hand bone.

[image]

When selecting the metarig, in pose mode, if I move the hand, the sword will move accordingly. Eg with a rotation:

[image]

However, when selecting the rig, in pose mode, moving the hand won't affect the sword, whereas I would expect the sword to follow.

[image]

Any idea on what I am getting wrong?

Here is a link to my blender file in case it helps: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V_9jYf4NxqcltW-dOrMjVm11PDAizgDI/view?usp=sharing

Thank you

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @DuarteFarrajotaRamos. Since this duplicate received an answer that resolves my problem, I deleted the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine, you need to select the correct armature (*rig*) and the correct bone (*hand_ik.R*) in the *Child Of* constraint:

[image]

The rig called *metarig* has been used to generate *rig*, *metarig* is not used anymore (but keep it nevertheless). Result:

[image]

Comment: Good to mention: the armature object named `metarig` is only Rigify's tool to generate the full-featured rig. Once the rig is generated, you shouldn't touch the metarig at all. It's good practice to hide it or put it in a collection and disable that collection to avoid unintentional changes. The metarig is very useful to re-generate the rig if you broke something.

Comment: Yes that's what i tried to say in my edit   ;)